# Add users in shell script with txt file

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I want to add some users who are in this file like:

```
a b
c d
e f
```

firstname lastname always

```
#!/bin/bash
Lines=$(cat newusers.txt | wc -l)


first=$(cat newusers.txt | awk '{print $1}')
last=$(cat newusers.txt | awk '{print $2}')

#test
echo $Lines;
echo $first;
echo $last;

until [ -z $1]; then

useradd - m -d /home/$1 -c "$1 + $2" $1

fi
```

before loop it works fine but I can't add newline.
The echo shows `a c e` and second for lastname `b d f`.
I tried to add newline in but it doesn't works.

What can i use for this?
Because I guess I can't add the user because of the newline problem.

I also searched on stackoverflow to find out a way to check if the user already exists by `/dev/null` but which variable do i have to use for it?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to process the file line by line:

```
while read first last ; do
    useradd -m -d /home/"$first" -c "$fist + $last" "$first"
done < newusers.txt
```

Comment: you write while read first last. But that are the lines right?

Comment: Just one more question i forgot to ask, where do i have to add the password?

Comment: @gladius: `read` reads line by line, but it can read several words from one line into several variables.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you mean to do by your code, but if you want to read the file line by line and get the values of different fields then you can use the following code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="newusers.txt"
while read -r line
do
    fn=$( echo "$line" |cut -d" " -f1 )
    ln=$( echo "$line" |cut -d" " -f2 )
    echo "$fn $ln"
done < "$filename"
```

Note: You cannot add users the way you want to using bash script; since you will be prompted for password which must be supplied using `tty` you can use `expect` to program it; or use system calls.